# sql server 2012 query for finding particular day

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

In SQL server, if user enter any date then control should always goes to 7 days back then check either it is Thursday or not, then print that day otherwise it should give coming Thursday.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Since weeks usually have 7 days, it would be Thursday today too, if it was 7 days ago...

Answer (score 0):

With a **7 days** week which seems to be the most widely used type of week, 7 days ago was most likely a Thursday if today is Thursday.

In this context, this code gives you the date which is 7 days before @date if it is not a Thursday. Otherwise it gives the date which is 7 days after @date.

```
Select [DayOfWeek] = datepart(dw,@date)
    , [DayName] = datename(dw, @date)
    , [Date] = case when datepart(dw,@date) <> 5 then dateadd(DAY,-7, @date) else dateadd(DAY,7, @date) end
```